# I want to rewrite URI in VirtualService for from regex to regex

Tags: kubernetes, routes, kubernetes-ingress, istio, gateway

I want to run the following API. While I want to run the following script. But I am not able to get the expected output.

```
 - match:
      uri:
        regex: \/test\/pune/\/(.+)\/bk
   rewrite:
      uri: \/pune/\/(.+)\/bk
    route:
    - destination:
        host: yerwada
        port:
          number: 8080
```

But I am getting following output -

> {"level":50,"time":1581684841254,"pid":18,"hostname":"test-ob-scheduled-payments-7cfb6779b8-x6f9b","err":{"type":"Error","message":"Parse
>   Error","stack":"Error: Parse
>   Error","bytesParsed":4,"code":"HPE_INVALID_URL","rawPacket":{"type":"Buffer","data":[71,69,84,32,92,47,99,100,115,45,97,117,92,47,118,49,92,47,98]}},"v":1}

Answer (score 2):

[HttpRewrite](https://istio.io/docs/reference/config/networking/virtual-service/#HTTPRewrite) cannot use regex, it can only accept string values.

Comment: I doubt there is any other way. You need to give exact URL as per the documentation.